# Advanced date range calculation excluding weekends and holidays

Tags: javascript, date, range

I have gotten my script to calculate from start to end date, but the more I did this, the more I realized what had to be calculated...

The company I am writing this for has a 'Request Off' page. Two text boxes allow the client to enter the start and end date in mm/dd/yyyy format. I currently have it calling the `dateRange()` function onchange. This processes the two dates, then updates the printed count within the SPAN.

Now the challenge. Within this range, I have to exclude weekends, which I have seen examples of, but cannot understand. I also have to exclude what this company considers Paid Holidays, which also have to be avoided as well if they land within range, but on a weekend.

Javascript Function:

```
function dateRange() {
  var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
  var firstDate = new Date(document.getElementById('start').value);
  var secondDate = new Date(document.getElementById('end').value);
  var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime())/(oneDay)-1));
  // holDays = ?????;
  // vacDays = diffDays - holDays;
  document.getElementById("holDays").innerHTML = diffDays || 0;
  document.getElementById("vacDays").innerHTML = diffDays || 0;
}
```

HTML Date Inputs:

```
From: <INPUT type="text" name="start" id="start" value="" onchange="dateRange()" class="datepicker" />
To: <INPUT type="text" name="end" id="end" value="" onchange="dateRange()" class="datepicker" />
```

Position to hold remaining count:

```
Paid Off Days: <SPAN id="holDays">0</SPAN> of the days in your range are Paid Holidays and will not be charged Vacation Days.
Vacation Days: You will be using <SPAN id="vacDays">0</SPAN> Day(s) of vacation.
```

So, need original count, excluding weekends.
Count of Holiday days within that range, not on a weekend.
Original count - Holiday count = Vacation Days

Comment: You've included PHP. Please show the final HTML unless you think the PHP is important...

Answer (score 1):

Well, I got no response here, but to offer my result in accomplishing such with a sample set of holiday dates...

```
function dateCount() {
  var startDate = new Date(document.getElementById('start').value);
  var endDate = new Date(document.getElementById('end').value);
  var holiDates = [];
  holiDates[0] = new Date("01/16/2013");
  holiDates[1] = new Date("04/20/2013");
  holiDates[2] = new Date("01/16/2014");
  var length = holiDates.length, fullCount = 0, paidCount = 0, vacDays = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    holiday = holiDates[i].getDay();
    if(holiDates[i] >= startDate && holiDates[i] <= endDate && holiday != 0 && holiday != 6) {
      paidCount++;
    }
  }
  while (startDate <= endDate) {
    var day = startDate.getDay();
    if(day != 0 && day != 6) {
      fullCount++; 
    }
    startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + 1); 
  }
  document.getElementById("holDays").innerHTML = paidCount || 0;
  vacDays = fullCount - paidCount;
  document.getElementById("vacDays").innerHTML = vacDays || 0;
}
```